# How to display time_ago in another function

Tags: php, scope, custom-function

This function is to display what inside my table but i can't figure out how to dislay time_ago function where it should display seconds or hours or weeks just want to display seconds hour or week instead of month day and year but i get an error Call to undefined function time_ago() i don't know what i did wrong but i just can figure it out what went wrong with my code. got error on line 505 which is this ---> ' . time_ago($row['lastupdate']) . '

```
    public static function getTicketByUserID(){
            $mysqli = dbConnect();
        $sql = "select
          t.id as ticketid,
        t.clientid,
        t.comments,
        t.assigneduser,  
      t.subject,
        t.user,
        t.lastupdate,
      t.opendate,
        (select c.department_name from department c where c.department_id = t.categoryid) as category,
        (select ts.status
          from ticketstatus ts
            where ts.ticketid = t.id
            and ts.statusdate = (select max(ts2.statusdate)
                                        from ticketstatus ts2
                                        where ts.ticketid = ts2.ticketid)) as status
          from tickets t
            where t.user = '". $_SESSION['name'] ."'
            and (select ts.status
          from ticketstatus ts
            where ts.ticketid = t.id
            and ts.statusdate = (select max(ts2.statusdate)
                                        from ticketstatus ts2
                                        where ts.ticketid = ts2.ticketid)) <> 'Closed'
             order by t.opendate desc";




    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
   echo '<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive"><th>User</th><th>Subject</th><th>Group</th><th>Created</th><th>Last update</th><th>Status</th>';
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['status'] == 'Closed') { $class = "btn btn-danger";}
        elseif ($row['status'] == 'Open') { $class = "btn btn-success";}
        elseif ($row['status'] == 'Waiting on Client') {$class = "btn btn-info";}
        else { $class = "btn btn-warning"; }
              echo '<tr class="table_row">
                    <td>' .$row['user'] .'</td>
                    <td>' .$row['subject'] .'</td>

                    <td>' . $row['category'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['opendate'])) . '</td>
                    <td>' . time_ago($row['lastupdate']) . '</td>
                    <td><form method="POST">
                      <input name="ticketId" value="' . $row['ticketid'] . '" type="text" hidden />
                      <button type="submit"   class="'.$class .'">'.$row['status'] .'</button></form>
                    </td>
                  </tr>';
      }
    } else {
      echo '</table>';
      $conn->close();
    }
```

This is my function for time_ago get this error Call to undefined function time_ago()  what did i do wrong?

```
function time_ago($ts)
{
  $mins = floor((gmtime() - $ts)/60);
  $hours = floor($mins/60);
  $mins -= $hours*60;
  $days = floor($hours/24);
  $hours -= $days*24;
  $weeks = floor($days/7);
  $days -= $weeks*7;

     if ($weeks == 1)
       $w = "week";
    elseif ($weeks > 1 && $weeks < 5)
       $w = "weeks";
    elseif ($weeks > 4)
       $w = "weeks";
    if ($weeks >= 1){
       $we = "".$weeks." ".$w."";
    }

    if ($days == 1)
       $d = "day";
    elseif ($days > 1 && $days < 5)
       $d = "day";
    elseif ($days > 4)
       $d = "days";
    if ($days >= 1 ){
       $da = "".$days." ".$d."";
    }

    if ($hours == 1)
       $h = "hour";
    elseif ($hours > 1 && $hours < 5)
       $h = "hour";
    elseif ($hours > 4)
       $h = "hours";
    if ($hours >= 1){
       $ho = "".$hours." ".$h."";
    }

    if ($mins > 10 && $mins < 15)
       $m = "minute";
    elseif (($mins%10) == 1)
       $m = "minute";
    elseif (($mins%10) > 1 && ($mins%10) < 5)
       $m = "minutes";
    elseif (($mins%10) > 4)
       $m = "minute";
    if ($mins >= 1){
       $mi = "".$mins." ".$m."";
    }else{
       $mi = "less than a minute";
    }

    if ($weeks || $days || $hours || $mins)
      return $we." ".$da." ".$ho." ".$mi;
}
```

Comment: Where are you initialising the file which contains that function?

Comment: same file and class

Comment: It seems your `time_ago()` function is out of `getTicketByUserID()`'s scope.  Please show us how these two snippets fit together in your class.  Rather than relying on arithmetic/division, would you entertain the use of a DateTime object?

Comment: i already fixed it but it display  March 12, 2018, 12:49 pm 578 Months ago instead of 1 second or 1 minutes ?